# How to prevent a SWF from running on a site other than ours?

Tags: encryption, flash, cracking, swf-decompiler

We've discovered that a Chinese site has figured out how to decrypt our SWFs, decompile them, then bypass any code which we put in to try to prevent the SWF from being run on any website other than ours.

As the Chinese programmers are gaining access to code, we need to figure out another way to stop them from running the SWF on their website -- at least during the limited exclusivity period on our site (usually a week or two).

I've proposed and so far our dev group has rejected making the SWF a simple client, thereby putting all of the game logic on our servers.

I've also proposed encrypting a SWF within an encrypted SWF, per this article -- http://www.veryinteractivepeople.com/?p=525 -- but based upon the comments, I don't think that it would help us.

Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would have to find some key part of the logic (not just a verification code) and make it a WebService.

It should

- not be easy to guess/replace
- use small bandwidth
- not be to critical for the reaction time

Comment: Hi Henk, are you suggesting that the SWF periodically call home to some service we host and have the SWF misbehave (i.e. the game becomes unplayable) if it doesn't get an appropriate response?  Or are you suggesting that we set up a server which sends data periodically to the SWF?

Comment: The WCF calling home is the simplest and most efficient. But it should be an essential service, not just a check. That would be removed.